# Laptop keyboard cable not working properly

Tags: laptop, keyboard

I have a strange issue with my laptop’s keyboard. Buttons “F2, F3, 3, E, D, C” stopped working suddenly. They were clearly in the same column, below each other. I opened the back of the laptop and cleaned the keyboard cable with an alcohol swab and it started working again properly. After few days the same issue happened again and the above buttons stopped working. I tried removing the cable from it’s socket and placing it again, tried pressing on the socket notch; however none of the above worked. Then I tried the alcohol solution and it worked perfectly - but again - after few days they stopped working again. I bought an electronics cleaning solution spray in case there was some sort of short circuit caused by dust, however, it did the same as alcohol and buttons worked few days then stopped working again.

Anyone has an explanation or solution for this issue guys?

Thank you

Comment: The problem likely is the cable itself, it could also be the keyboard's PCB, in either case the replacement of the part likely isn't worth the cost but only you can decide if that's the case.

Comment: On a mechanical-switch keyboard, I've seen surface-mount components come unsoldered on one side or even pop off the PCB. Since the two that came off were just diodes, they were easily replaced with 1N914 diodes with leads I had on hand. Check the PCB thoroughly with a magnifier for a similar issue.